# Is Reinforcement Learning suitable for optimal control problems in which actions influence rewards but not states?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, finance

In particular, rewards $r = f(s, a, s')$, but states are independent of actions $s' = g(s)$. A example could be asset trading that actions (long, short, hold) of a small trader won't affect market prices.

Edit: Just did some quick search and seems like this is a contextual bandit problem. Then is it possible to directly apply RL algorithms to these problems? Intuitively it might be less efficient to directly apply the methods, since $a$ is redundant for the state transition.

Comment: It seems like your edit has a different question than your title. Can you clarify what exactly it is you are interested in learning? If you have a new question different from this one, you're allowed to ask it -- just click the Ask Question button.

Comment: Take a look on a project of mine https://github.com/zkid18/coinmarket
But I guess in a every paper related to to RL in finance you will find the zero-market impact assumption. It says that your agent can't affect the market dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about finance to say if stock trades are optimal control problems, but an example of using RL for stock trades can be found in Maxim Lapan, *Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-On*. [The code corresponding to the chapter is on Github](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/tree/master/Chapter08).

Naturally, the problem is going about producing an RL agent that can do anything profitable. The agent proposed and tested in the book chapter fails to generalize, suggesting that this particular agent wouldn't be profitable at all.